# Test SalesforceDX CLI Plug-in documentation

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx-cli

Does anybody knows where can I found the documentation explaining how to test SalesforceDX Plug-ins?
I am asking specifically about *testing* SFDX CLI Plugins and not how to create the Plug-ins.